# using NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Given this dictionary:

```
"vals":[
{
"ID":"1",
"NAME":"Jack"
},
{
"ID":"2",
"NAME":"Jason"
},
{
"ID":"3",
"NAME":"Sheryl"
},
{
"ID":"4",
"NAME":"Clark"
},
{
"ID":"5",
"NAME":"Markus"
}]
```

I am using pickerView's method:

```
NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

So, given the NSInteger `row`, how do I get the name of that ID?

Comment: Isn't that actually an Array of dictionaries?

Comment: @nickfalk its a dictionary, whose only element is an array of dictionaries

Comment: why not just using id as the key and name as the value?

Comment: What is exactly the question? The title isn't even a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very basic way:

```
for (NSDictionary *idDictionary in [root objectForKey:@"vals"])
{
    NSInteger idValue = [[idDictionary objectForKey:@"ID"] integerValue];
    if (idValue == row)
        return [idDictionary objectForKey:@"NAME"]
}
```

although you should probably remember that the pickerView rows begin at 0, so you need to account for this

edit: you should add a return nil or @"" after the loop to catch the case where the item is missing. But as xlc0212 pointed out above, a different data structure would work better. My suggestion would be to have a dictionary like:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = @{@"vals" : @[@"Jack", @"Jason", @"Sheryl", @"Clark", @"Markus"]};
NSString *value = [[myDict objectForKey:@"vals"] objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: +1, what i tried you had same

Comment: Right following your for loop he could add `return @"";` to make sure that an empty string (not nil but something the picker can deal with) is returned in the event, that there is no ID corresponding to row. Plus of course it should be 'for (idValue - 1 = row)' with respect to the first row beeing zero.

Comment: @HermannKlecker correct. this is very basic, no error checking, and will definitely not give a value for the first value as the dictionary now is set up

Answer (score 0):

As `vals` is an array of dictionaries you can just pick a row from array:

```
NSArray *values = [dict objectForKey:@"vals"];
NSDictionary *value = [values objectAtIndex:row];
return (NSString *) [value objectForKey:@"NAME"];
```

`row` won't match ID cause your IDs starts from 1 and `row` values from 0.
If you need ID for some reasons I would rather suggest to get it when picker row will be selected:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    self.myID = [[[self.myData objectForKey:@"vals"] objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"ID"]
}
```

Anyway if your IDs are always just indexes like 1,2,3,4,5... (without any holes like 1,2,5,10) then your ID is equal `row+1` and you don't need to search for it.

Comment: That should work fine unless the values need to be sorted by ID. An NSDictionary does not guarantee any specific order (although it always had in all cases when I used them).

Comment: I agree, but note that `vals` is an array in this example - it will keep an order

Comment: You are right of course.